# Can anyone request to access our moderators room?

Tags: support, chat, moderator-tools

I am a new moderator at [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com), and we have a chat room just for moderators, it is called "Soft Towers". Now a popup saying `XYZ has requested access to Soft Towers` has appeared:

[image]

Can *anyone* request to access our moderators room? (Sounds time-wasting as we probably won't allow anyone who does not get elected)
Or is it just people who have a very valid reason to? (for instance Stack employees)

Comment: Stack Exchange employees will just be able to request a diamond and walk right in if necessary :)

Comment: Not quite so easy, @ChrisF - we don't just hand off diamonds to every employee... but we do to those that have a reason for it.

Comment: @Oded - Yeah, I realised that just after I hit "return".

Comment: I cannot think of a situation where I would approve anyone entering a moderator room who did not already have access to it.

Comment: Rooms set to private (as opposed to gallery mode) aren't publicly listed - so those who can see them already have the privileges to join them if they want. It sounds like if someone already has a direct link to the room, then they're able to request access though...

Comment: Aw, was so excited about the pepperblocker but then @Doorknob冰 ruined it for me--it's just some stupid random brush in gimp.  Hashtag heartbroken hashtag this isn't twitter

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Can anyone request to access our moderators room?

Yes.

---

Now, these rooms are setup for moderators (and CMs and to a lesser extent devs) to be able to talk about different issues, including users of the site and as such are off-limits to other users (thus - private rooms).

In rooms that are protected this way, people tend to discuss things that fall under the moderator agreement (say, details of finding sock puppets, or disclosing personally identifying information of users - these are things that are bound by the moderator agreement).

As such, people that do not *already* have access to these rooms most probably should not have access to them.

tl;dr

Ignore such requests.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. A mod room is just another room; it functions like any other private room on the chat network. Anyone can discover that there is a room *there*, and anyone can request access to it.

In general, you can safely ignore this - unless it's another mod who you know has a reason to have access, anyone who needs to see that room can already see it (or can persuade a dev to get them in).